# Regex to find suffixes in names

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm having trouble writing a regular expression that would find and remove suffixes in names in strings. I had it working fine just looking for the suffix (e.g. 'III', 'IV'), until I had names with IV start appearing. I know the logic once I get the location of the suffix to remove it, I'm just having trouble writing the expression to find the suffix without getting part of someone's name.

Example string
`LSU JUMPER BY #03 ROBINSON III`

Last names will ALWAYS be preceded by a number then space, the lines are always all caps,  and the suffix will always be the last thing in the line. I've tried '[A-Z] III$' and '[A-Z]\sIII$' as well as those variations without the $. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both of your regexes say "exactly one capital letter followed by a space then III at the end of the string" without the dollar says the same, but anywhere in the string

Comment: you can't remove anything from a string, strings are immutable in python

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: If I understand your problem, you have matching regexp but you can't distinguish properly between `LSU JUMPER BY #03 ROBINSON IV` and `LSU JUMPER BY #03 ANTONIV`? I think in general you'll need more information, especially if names can contain spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use re.split to remove suffixes in names. The following regex should match for ALL roman numerals (whether if they're valid or not)

```
\s[IVX][IVX]+
```

So to use re.split,

```
re.split(r'\s[IVX][IVX]+', put_string_here)
```

will return what you're looking for.

Edit: Assuming there is ALWAYS a space between the last name and the suffix.

Comment: Let's hope there will never be a President George XIV Bush, let alone anything with C, D, or M.

Comment: You're right. It's very unlikely anyone will have C, D, M as a suffix as well..., I tried restricting it further. Hopefully there isn't any more errors in my logic

Comment: This worked fine, I just added an $ to the end. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If the suffix is in the form of roman numerals, focus on that.

This regex:

```
([A-Z]+ (?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$)
```

will match your description for roman numerals I - IX.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH2jM0/2)